# Usar ponto no lugar de vírgula no teclado numérico com Linux Mint

Tags: linux, teclado, mint, bind

Estou usando o **Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa**

No meu teclado numérico o botão do ponto (**.**) ao clicar insere vírgula (**,**)

Tentei entrar nas configurações porém não achei a opção que faça essa mudança

Há como configurar para que o comportamento do meu botão faça isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solução via linha de comando:

Para usar o ponto no lugar da vírgula no teclado numérico, abra o terminal e execute o seguinte comando:

```
echo 'xmodmap -e "keycode 129 = period"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Esse comando irá fixar essa alteração inclusive após o reiniciar o computador

Nesse caso essa alteração será apenas para o usuário atual que usar o comando

---

#### Solução editando arquivos de inicialização:

Para fazer a alteração manualmente editando os arquivos, procure pelo aquivo `.bashrc` ou `bash.bashrc`

Primeiramente identifique qual Arquivo de inicialização você pretende editar:

- Arquivo de inicialização sistema: `/etc/bash.bashrc`
- Arquivo de inicialização pessoal: `/home/seuNome/.bashrc` ou `~/.bashrc`

Escolha um desses 2 arquivos e adicione na última linha:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 129 = period"
```

Para saber em qual melhor arquivo de inicialização editar, recomendo entrar nesse [link](https://sobrelinux.info/questions/9560/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-and-etc-bash-bashrc), que há uma explicação mais detalhada da diferença desses aquivos e qual é a ordem de execução deles.

---

#### Referência:

[Viva o Linux - Como usar ponto no lugar da vírgula no teclado numérico](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Tecla-ponto-do-teclado-numerico-mostrando-virgula-em-programas-instalados-via-Wine)